# facebook js sdk post to wall

Tags: facebook, sdk

i am struggling to ad the post to wall functionality to an existing piece of code ?
It works fine with logging in and obtaing email for form submit, i would like it to post to wall on log in as well ! in the simplist way possible .?
URL to see it in action is http://lproctor.co.uk/.

```
    // The facebook JavaScript SDK to log in to FB
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    FB.ui(
  {
   method: 'feed',
   name: 'The Facebook SDK for Javascript',
   caption: 'Bringing Facebook to the desktop and mobile web',
   description: (
      'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
      'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
      'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
   ),
   link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/',
   picture: 'http://www.fbrell.com/public/f8.jpg'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
```

NOW USING

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    // The facebook JavaScript SDK to log in to FB
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true
        });
    FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
         name: 'Facebook name',
     link: 'http://lproctor.co.uk/',
     picture: 'http://lproctor.co.uk/logo.jpg',
     caption: 'facebook caption',
     description: ' facebook description facebook description facebook description facebook description',
     message: 'Facebook message!'
   },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      };


      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());


    </script>
```

Comment: Please describe how it fails. Do any errors appear in the browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: No fail errors. The log in works fine and the email and name are collected into form, it just doesnt post to wall ?SRY there is an error

Comment: FB is not defined  !   FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {

Comment: Don't post code blocks in comments...

Comment: You are trying to call `FB.ui` outside of the `fbAsyncInit` handler – and in combination with asynchronous loading of the SDK file that just means, there _is_ no FB object available yet.

Comment: thanks looking into that now, i have something working but quite there yet  @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // connected
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // not_authorized
        login();
    } else {
        // not_logged_in
        login();
    }
});
};
```

Comment: um come again ? please see revised code and problem is east to recreate by going to lproctor.co.uk